# It is necessary that when pointing to the link under it there appeared a block with links

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a link that is placed in `li` and when you hover on it, a block should appear with links that I will indicate in it

```
<li id="dropdown" class="li">
    <a href="/news/">Lessons</a>
</li>
<div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: your html is invalid, you can't have div right next to li. also what have you tried? what didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are u expecting like this:

```css
   a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
 font-family: monospace;
}

ul {
  background: darkorange;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
}

li {
 color: #fff;
 background: #5c8ff6;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 padding: 1rem;
 position: relative;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
  
li a {
  color: #fff;
}

li:hover {
 background: black;
 cursor: pointer;
}

ul li ul {
 background: orange;
 visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  min-width: 5rem;
 position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin-top: 1rem;
 left: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover > ul,
ul li ul:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}

ul li ul li {
 clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Lessons</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a dropdown menu like this? https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp

The example on the website

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```